# Responsive layout messed up in IE

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser, responsive-design

So I'm sorry if the answer is completely obvious. This is my first website ever, and I'm building it for a web development class as well as for the business itself (for free). I'm trying.

I've been attempting to make a responsive layout but I have only been able to check my site in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari because I'm on a Mac. I also used browsershots but it was hard to determine what it looked like at smaller sizes. My sister just sent me what the site looks like in IE 10 on her computer and it's certainly not what I was hoping for. The site looks fine at the normal screen size but when she makes it smaller it just destroys itself. Everything below the navigation bar appears to have, well, disappeared or moved far down the screen or something.

Here is the page I'm dealing with right now: http://stweb.ccv.edu/CIS-1151-VO02-V13FA/kak10200/project_03/steel.html (the only other pages running at the moment are the home page and the custom residential doors).

What the heck is wrong? I thought I was doing fine!

Furthermore, I used a table (and tried to make it responsive) to put all of the door images on there. I think that also is messed up in IE at a small screen size. Any idea why?

Ugh. This is tough.

Comment: Giving it a quick check it looks the same in firefox and ie 10 to me. Is it just a case of her updating the cache?

Comment: Even when you bring the screen size down? It looked fine to her at her normal screen size too but completely messes up when you make it smaller.

Comment: I checked it right now and it looks in IE10 the same like in chrome. When I do the smallest u can and on full screen. Looks like your code is fine

Comment: Awesome! That's great to hear. Hopefully it works for the other versions of IE too. Must have been an issue with her computer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was covered in the comments on your question, this was probably an issue with caching where her computer had old resources stored on her computer.

Avoid this problem in the future by, for instance, adding version numbers to the names of your static resources (such as CSS-documents).

As for future browser testing, check out [BrowserStack](http://www.browserstack.com/) for live testing in any relevant browser. It's an incredibly neat tool.